# Python How to use for loop to fill sublists in a list

Tags: python, for-loop, sublist

There is a list of some tuples and it would be easy to format this list to a list of lists by using a *list comprehension*. However, how can I do the same thing by using for loop?

```
some_tuples = [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)]
[[x for x in a_tuple] for a_tuple in some_tuples]
```

The output will be:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

I tried to use for loop

```
a_tuple = []
for i in some_tuples:
    for x in i:
        a_tuple.append([x])
a_tuple
```

The output will be:

```
[[1], [2], [3], [4], [5], [6], [7], [8], [9]]
```

How can I get `[[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]` without using the *list comprehension*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your list comprehension :

```
print([[x for x in a_tuple] for a_tuple in some_tuples])
```

is same as:

```
final_result=[]
for a_tuple in some_tuples:
    sub_result=[]
    for x in a_tuple:
        sub_result.append(x)
    final_result.append(sub_result)

print(final_result)
```

output:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Comment: Yeah that’s what I expected, an explanation of list comprehension. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

use `list()` to convert a tuple to a list:

```
some_tuples = [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)]

a_tuple = []
for i in some_tuples:
    a_tuple.append(list(i))

print(a_tuple)
```

#### Results:

```
[[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Comment: thank you so much. actually i expect a way of filling sublists rather than directly converting tuple to list. lol

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way without using list comprehension is to map your inner tuples to a list:

```
some_tuples = [(1, 2, 3), (4, 5, 6), (7, 8, 9)]
some_lists = map(list, some_tuples)  # list(map(list, some_tuples)) on Python 3.x
print(some_lists)  # [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I know about map() from you. Actually I expect a way to fill sublists rather than directly generate lists from tuples. lol